# <__main__.Empleado object at 0x000002D34EA51FD0> , porque aparece esto en vez de una lista

Tags: python, objeto

Quiero que me arroje los resultados en una lista o formato entendible para mortales, NO como me arroja <**main**.Empleado object at 0x000002D34EA51FD0>, en vez de eso quiero que aparezca el return

Este es el codigo que he escrito no se en que me de podido equivocar

```
class Empleado:

    def __init__(self,nombre,cargo,salario):   
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.cargo=cargo
        self.salario=salario

    
    def ___str__(self):

        return "{} que trabaja como {} tiene un salario de {} $".format(self.nombre, self.cargo, self.salario)

        

listaempleados=[

Empleado("Juan", "Director", 200),
Empleado("Ana", "Presidenta", 300),
Empleado("Julia", "Jefe", 50),
Empleado("Pedro", "Botones", 30)
]


def calculo_comision(empleado):
    empleado.salario=empleado.salario*1.03 
    return empleado

ListaEmpleadosComision=map(calculo_comision,listaempleados)

for empleado in ListaEmpleadosComision:
    print (empleado)
```

Cuando le doy correr en vez de aparecerme texto como "Juan que trabaja como Director tiene un salario de 200" me aparece `<__main__.Empleado object at 0x000002D34EA51FD0>`

Answer (score 1):

Escribistes:

```
def ___str__(self):
```

(con tres "_" al principio).

Debes escribir

```
def __str__(self):
```

(dos "__" por cada lado).

Es un problema recurrente; no se distingue.

Answer (score 0):

for empleado in ListaEmpleadosComision:
print (empleado.salario)

Agrega esta linea al final espero te ayude – X@nd@¬

Comment: Resuktado : 206.0
309.0
51.5